# Trying to get all links in my posts

Tags: loop, query, search, links

I am trying to return all the links inside my posts'/pages' content, but I can't figure out how to get my regex/loop to work right. Here is what I have at the moment, that just returns a bunch of empty arrays when I `print_r($matches)`. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to provide more details.

```
function find_all_links() {
    // Let's get the posts
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,  
    ) );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        // Start a list
        $results = '<br><ul>';

        // For each list item...
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            // Get the post
            $the_query->the_post();

            // Get the post content
            $content = get_the_content();

            preg_match_all("/<a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*([\"\']??)([^\"\' >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU", $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

            if (!empty($matches)) {
                foreach ($matches as $match) {
                    $results .= '<li> '.$match.' (<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" target="_blank">' . get_the_title() . '</a>)</li>';
                }
            }
        }

        // End the list
        $results .= '</ul>';
    } else {
        // no posts found
        $results = 'No posts found.';
    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I noticed my theme was actually replacing all the anchor tags with shortcodes for SEO purposes, so there weren't any links in the content anymore. I was able to make it work by replacing

`$content = get_the_content();`

with

`$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );`